# I have the following problem: Let $|x_{n+1} - x_n| < 1/3^n$. Show that $(x_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

We have that $(x_n)$ is a sequence of real numbers. And the relation on the title:
$$
|x_{n+1} - x_n| < \frac{1}{3^n}.
$$
We must prove that this is a Cauchy sequence.

I know that an Cauchy sequence follows the definition:

given $\epsilon>0$, exists $n_0 > 0$, such that
$m,n > n_o \Rightarrow |x_m - x_n|< \epsilon$

But I don't know how to use both informations to prove the exercise.

If someone please may help me, I'd be very thankful.

Comment: Estimate $|x_n-x_m|$ and use the fact that the sum $\sum 1/3^n$ converges

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**
$$
|x_{n+k}-x_n | = |x_{n+k}-x_{n+k-1}+x_{n+k-1}-x_{n+k-2}+....+ x_{n+1}-x_n| \\
\leq |x_{n+k}-x_{n+k-1}|+|x_{n+k-1}-x_{n+k-2}|+....+| x_{n+1}-x_n| 
$$

Comment: thank you very much